# I'm building a social app with flutter and firebase. Need a way to fetch and update conversations in real-time

Tags: flutter, firebase

The basic idea of what I'm trying to build is as follows:

A social app where people can create "groups", and under each group any user can create "chatrooms" where a bunch of users can get on an talk about some topic. If you're a user and you enter a group and send a message in a chat room, you can navigate to a separate screen later ("my conversations") to get back to the conversation. This screen should show all conversations that you are a part of (or rather, have sent a message in). Similar to any messaging app, the screen needs to be updated in real time whenever someone sends a message in one of the groups I'm a part of.

My current firebase structure is as follows:

- chatRooms (chatRoomId, groupId, lastMessageSent, lastMessageTimestamp)
- - - messages (userId, text, timestamp)
      |
- chatRoomParticipants (chatRoomId, userId)
  |
- groups (groupId, title, createdBy)
  |
- groupMembers (userId, groupId)
  |
- Users (userId)
- - - myChatRooms (chatRoomId)

where

- - - represents a subcollection

I need to fetch all chatRooms that a user has sent a message in (myChatRooms), sort them by lastMessageTimestamp, and if someone were to send a message in one of these chatRooms while I'm on this screen it needs to update the list in real time. The tricky part is also paginating this to fetch 10-20 chatrooms at a time, as users may be part of hundreds of chatRooms and some metadata needs to be fetched while rendering the chatRooms.

The problem here is that the lastMessageTimestamp is being stored in the `chatRooms` collection, while I'm using the `myChatRooms` subcollection to store the ids of all chatRooms relevant to the user.

I'm not sure how to make a call to fetch 10 at a time, while also updating the `myConversations` screen whenever someone sends a message in real time.

Comment: the firebase library has a .snapshots() function on the firebaseCollection object where you can listen for changes and emits the changes to the streambuilder that is listening to it